# POS-tagging a sentence using NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, part-of-speech

I would like to pos tag a sentence using the NLTK library in python.
I am using the following couple of lines of code and it works fine:

```
>>> text = word_tokenize("And now for something completely different")
>>> nltk.pos_tag(text)
[('And', 'CC'), ('now', 'RB'), ('for', 'IN'), ('something', 'NN'),
('completely', 'RB'), ('different', 'JJ')]
```

However,  I would like to output the POS as properties of a node class variable (ie. sentence).
For instance, I would like to have my output for a sentence like "james ate ..." be like

```
sentence.noun = “james”
sentence.verb = “ate”
sentence.adjective = “ … “
```

Any idea on how my code should change?

Answer (score 0):

In order to that you need to create a `Sentence` class which has attributes.

```py
class Sentence:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text
        self.noun = None
        self.verb = None
        self.adjective = None

text = "And now for something completely different"
tokens = word_tokenize(text)
s = Sentence(text)
for w, t in nltk.pos_tag(text):
    if t == 'NN':
        s.noun = w
    elif t == 'VB':
        s.verb = w
    # etc ...
```

With this approach you cannot have multiple verbs in your sentence.

Depending on your goal you can check [spacy](https://spacy.io/usage/linguistic-features) which offers high level processing of string (you can access named entities and noun_phrases for example). Or maybe you can check the task of dependency parsing (example [here](https://explosion.ai/demos/displacy)) from which you can extract phrases and which verb relates to which subject etc...